# In SQLite, how do I select elements in one table that are not in other?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've two tables in SQLite:

```
Table1:
-------
id
name

Table2:
-------
id
temp_name
```

My question is, how do I write an SQL query that returns names in `Table2` that are not in `Table1`?

For example:

```
Table1:
-------
1, 'john'
2, 'boda',
3, 'cydo',
4, 'linus'

Table2:
-------
1123, 'boda'
2992, 'andy',
9331, 'sille',
2,    'cydo'
```

In this example the SQL query should return elements `andy`, and `sille` from `Table2`, because they're not in `Table1`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how to do it in "obvious" standard SQL:

```
select *
from table2
where temp_name not in (select name from table1)
```

There are other methods, such as using `left outer join`, `exists` in the `where` clause, and the `except` operation.

Comment: How would the query look like with `EXCEPT`?

Comment: @bodacydo `SELECT id,temp_name FROM table2 EXCEPT SELECT id,name FROM table1`. Column count needs to be same on either side. Good explanation here: http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/except.php

Answer (score 5):

I was curious about which of the options would work best for my use case and thought it might be of help to others if I shared my results:

In short, *select where not in* is the speediest (for me!).
It's also worth noting that using all options returned duplicates except for *except*.

```
Option 0: SELECT {c2} FROM {t2} WHERE {c2} not in (SELECT {c1} FROM {t1});
    Entries returned: 1098, Unique entries returned: 357
    Average: 1.8680 seconds
    Entries returned: 0, Unique entries returned: 0
    Average: 0.6664 seconds
Option 1: SELECT {c2} FROM {t2} EXCEPT SELECT {c1} FROM {t1};
    Entries returned: 357, Unique entries returned: 357
    Average: 3.9455 seconds
    Entries returned: 0, Unique entries returned: 0
    Average: 3.3074 seconds
Option 2: SELECT {t2}.{c2} FROM {t2} LEFT OUTER JOIN {t1} ON {t1}.{c1} = {t2}.{c2} WHERE {t1}.{c1} IS null;
    Entries returned: 1098, Unique entries returned: 357
    Average: 2.3330 seconds
    Entries returned: 0, Unique entries returned: 0
    Average: 1.1982 seconds
Option 3: SELECT {c2} FROM {t2} WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM {t1} WHERE {c1} = {t2}.{c2});
    Entries returned: 1098, Unique entries returned: 357
    Average: 2.6945 seconds
    Entries returned: 0, Unique entries returned: 0
    Average: 0.9737 seconds
```

Here's the code I used to run the numbers:

```
import sqlite3
import timeit

# Database path here
database = "database.db"

# Your table and column names here
t1, c1 = 'Table_1', 'name'
t2, c2 = 'Table_2', 'temp_name'

# Reverse the test
dbs = [{'t1': t1, 'c1':c1, 't2': t2, 'c2': c2},
       {'t1': t2, 'c1':c2, 't2': t1, 'c2': c1}]

commands = ["SELECT {c2} FROM {t2} WHERE {c2} not in (SELECT {c1} FROM {t1});",
"SELECT {c2} FROM {t2} EXCEPT SELECT {c1} FROM {t1};",
"SELECT {c2} FROM {t2} LEFT OUTER JOIN {t1} ON {t1}.{c1} = {t2}.{c2} WHERE {t2}.{c2} IS null;",
"SELECT {c2} FROM {t2} WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM {t1} WHERE {c1} = {t2}.{c2});",]

for i, c in enumerate(commands):
    print("Option {}: {}".format(i, c))
    for db in dbs:
        co = c.format(**db)
        foo = sqlite3.connect(database).execute(co).fetchall()
        # Sanity check that entries have been found and how many
        print("\tEntries returned: {}, Unique entries returned: {}".format(len(foo), len({a[0] for a in foo})))
        # Reconnect to the database each time - I can't remember if there's any caching
        t = timeit.repeat(lambda: sqlite3.connect(database).execute(co).fetchall(), repeat=5, number=1)
        print('\tAverage: {:.4f} seconds'.format(statistics.mean(t)))
```

Comment: do you have the code that create those tables?

Answer (score 3):

```
select name
from table2
except
select temp_name
from table1
```

Answer (score 2):

The left join version:

```
select t2.* from Table2 t2
left outer join Table1 t1 on t1.name = t2.temp_name
where t2.temp_name is null
```

Answer (score 1):

The `EXISTS` method mentioned by Gordon:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table1
                  WHERE Table1.name = Table2.temp_name)
```

Comment: When I try an equivalent statement I get an error that says `Error: no such column: Table2.temp_name`. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @reubenjohn In this question, `Table2` has a column `temp_name`.