# Cannot filter based on "where not in"

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with two tables, each with the row `id`. I'm trying to filter data from table1 based on what is *not* in table2. Table1 has, for example:

```
In: SELECT id FROM table1 LIMIT 4
Out: 
'0000001'
'0000002
'0000003'
'0000004'
```

And table2 has:

```
In: SELECT id FROM table2 LIMIT 10
Out: 
None
None
None
'0001098'
'0001098'
'0001098'
'0001098'
'0001098'
'0001098'
'0001098'
```

I'd like to return all values from table1 whose id column is not in table2, which I try to do with:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

But this returns no values. If I use `SELECT id FROM table1 EXCEPT SELECT id FROM table2`, it works fine. As I understand, the `WHERE COLUMN NOT IN` is [the standard method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818736/in-sqlite-how-do-i-select-elements-in-one-table-that-are-not-in-other) to perform what I'm trying to do. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `id` in `table2` contains `null` values.
If you use this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE id IS NOT null)
```

it will work. 
I did not find anything in the **SQLite** documentation about this case, but for **MySQL** from: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

> To comply with the SQL standard, IN returns NULL not only if the
>   expression on the left hand side is NULL, but also if no match is
>   found in the list and one of the expressions in the list is NULL

So **this is SQL standard** and it means that in your case the statement:

```
IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

returns `NULL` and then

```
NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

also returns `NULL`. 
So your condition does not evaluate to `TRUE` and you don't get any results.

Answer (score 0):

Use NOT EXISTS instead

```
SELECT id 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
```